# How to add class dynamically from templates

Tags: functions, filters

I would like to add dynamic classes from templates to tags like `<main>`, `<header>`, `<footer>` which are defined in header.php and footer.php. This is something I would like to acheive:

header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <header class="<?php dynamic_header_class(); ?>">
        .
        .
        .
        .
    </header>
    <main class="<?php dynamic_main_class(); ?>">
        <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

about-template.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: About Page
*/
// Add header-interior class to <header>
set_header_class('header-interior');
// Add main-map-container class to <main>
set_main_class('main-map-container');
?>
```

contact-template.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Contact Page
*/
// Add header-exterior class to <header>
set_header_class('header-exterior');
// Add main-no-footer class to <main>
set_main_class('main-no-footer');
?>
```

Wordpress do have `body_class()` and `post_class()` but they are limited to `<body>` tag and corresponding `<div>` respectively. Coming from [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) which has a very easy way to do these things using `{% set %}` tag. Can something reusable function or filter be created in wordpress where I could add different classes from different templates to tags like `<main>`, `<header>` etc.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some examples of which classes you would like to be output in your markup? With specific examples it makes suggestions a lot easier. For example: `<header class="template-name post-id">`. This may be useful: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/references/list-of-conditional-tags/

Comment: Alternatively, WP's `body_class()` provides a lot of default classes, and you can add custom classes to it. You could use inheritance i.e. `body.page header` to affect inner elements.

Comment: yes, please post some code, what you want to achive.

Comment: @craig I would like to have classes like `<header class="modifier {$dynamicClass1}" >` from template A,  similarly `<header class="modifier {$dynamicClass2}" > ` from Template B. This are all CSS predefined class that change the look of of header accordingly. Also I don't want to use those conditional class, because there are atleast 10 templates, and as I asked in the question I need to add class on multiple tags like header, main, footer etc. Adding conditions would make things messy plus I want a more permanent and easy way of doing it using some type of custom function or filter.

Comment: @webelaine I'm migrating a big project to wordpress, a lot of changes had to be made in css for inheriting css through body class which would take alot of time. If it was a fresh project inheritance surely is a good idea.

Comment: @hashtagerrors I was asking for examples of the classes you wish to output to provide custom examples of a function I assume you are requesting. It's difficult to provide a succinct answer without getting deeper detail on your dynamic classes and a deeper explanation of your use case. I assume you are looking at either making your own `body_class()` function. Or alternatively you could look at implementing Twig. It's difficult to understand the Twig behaviour you've used VS the end result you want in WordPress, if I and others understood that we could perhaps reach an answer

Comment: WordPress doesn't have functions for this, but there's nothing stopping you writing your own.

Comment: @CraigPearson I have edited my question. Please see if it make sense. Also there is a way of implementing twig through Timber plugin, but I wouldn't like to do that. This is something I always wanted in Wordpress, and now that I have to do it, I would like to do it Wordpress way.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I would like to write it, but need a headstart.